# drawing unique elements with replacement

Tags: probability, generating-functions

I have a situation where I will draw a random number of balls from an urn with

- $r$ red balls
- and $b$ blue balls,

with $N=r+b$.  The number drawn is $k$, and I know the distribution $k$ comes from.

I would like a clean formula for the probability of $u$ distinct red balls.  Ideally in some form of generating function.

Thus far I've found that the probability of getting $\ell$ red balls (not necessarily distinct) is

$$\left(\frac{r}{N}\right)^\ell \frac{1}{\ell!} \mu^{(\ell)}(b/N)$$

where $\mu(x)$ is the probability generating function of $k$ and $\mu^{(\ell)}$ denotes the $\ell$-th derivative of $\mu$.

So I can get to a sum over all $\ell$ of the probability of $\ell$ red balls times the probability of $u$ unique balls among the $\ell$ red balls.  I'd like a compact way to express this though.  I haven't been able to come up with it.

---

**aside**

One nice property of the expression for the probability of $\ell$ red balls is that if we replace $r/N$ with $x-b/N$ then this is the $\ell$-th term of the Taylor Series expansion for $\mu(x)$ centered at $b/N$.  And in particular if $x=1$ then $1-b/N = r/N$.  So summing these terms over all $\ell$ will give $\mu(1)$, which is $1$.